# Dealing with good intentions but bad contributions

Tags: problem-users, user-behavior, stack-exchange

We have a user in our community (a stack exchange site) who is very well-intended in his efforts to help improve existing content, but consistently is providing low-quality edits, flagging things inappropriately, and mislabeling tags. We've talked to him both on the forum and separately in chat, but he doesn't seem to be changing. There is a definite language barrier at play as well, which makes it slightly more sensitive in my eyes. How else can we deal with this situation such that the community is not made the worse due to his work?

Comment: Duplicate? http://moderators.stackexchange.com/q/136/83

Comment: @MonicaCellio - Looks like it, actually.

Comment: @MonicaCellio this question mentions StackExchange specifically whereas the question you mention is broader in scope, and here the user has been dealt with several times already

Comment: @Malachi - Honestly, I'm not sure that's enough of a difference. If you think it may be, though, we can see whether this garners different answers.

Comment: @Malachi it's possible that the other question, in trying to be open and talk about behaviors not technologies, is actually too broad.  That's what we're here to find out in private beta.  (That's why I didn't cast the first close vote, just raised it in a comment.)

Comment: maybe they are duplicates. it looks like Monica's question is more in depth about it though?  what do you think @eykanal?

Comment: @Malachi - I'm fine with the dupe marking, I think question is more than good enough to answer this one.